# php xml read out max value on each days

Tags: php, xml

I have a problem where i tries to read out a max temperature value on each day from an xml file. My xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<temperature>
    <measure>
        <date>2013-06-19 03:18</date>
        <sensor1>25.38</sensor1>
    </measure>
    <measure>
        <date>2013-06-19 06:18</date>
        <sensor1>26.38</sensor1>
    </measure>
    <measure>
        <date>2013-06-19 09:18</date>
        <sensor1>30.31</sensor1>
    </measure>
    <measure>
        <date>2013-06-20 03:18</date>
        <sensor1>25.31</sensor1>
    </measure>
    <measure>
        <date>2013-06-20 06:18</date>
        <sensor1>23.34</sensor1>
    </measure>
    <measure>
        <date>2013-06-21 07:18</date>
        <sensor1>26.31</sensor1>
    </measure>
    <measure>
        <date>2013-06-21 10:18</date>
        <sensor1>25.31</sensor1>
    </measure>       
</temperature>
```

And what i want as output is like:

```
06/19 max 30.31
06/20 max 25.31
06/21 max 26.31
```

As im still learning php im stuck. The code i have produced so far is:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");
$days = array();
$sens1Array = array();
foreach($xml as $temp){
    $days[] = $temp->date . "," . $temp->sensor1;
}
$days = array_unique($days);
foreach($days as $day){                 
    $day= explode(",", $day);
    $time = date("m/d", strtotime($day[0]));
    echo $time . " ";
    echo "max " . $day[1];
    echo "<br>";        
}   
?>
```

Which outputs:

```
06/19 max 25.38
06/19 max 26.38
06/19 max 30.31
06/20 max 25.31
06/20 max 23.34
06/21 max 26.31
06/21 max 25.31
```

So what im looking for is some code that can compare each day and only output the max value for that day. I have searched and tried a lot but i can't solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think next code does what you want.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");


/* aggregation of sensor maximum day values over time */

$days = array();

foreach ($xml as $measure)
{
    $time   = date("m/d", strtotime($measure->date));
    $sensor = (float) $measure->sensor1;

     if (isset($days[$time]) and $days[$time] >= $sensor) {
         continue;
     }

     $days[$time] = $sensor;         
}


/* output */

foreach ($days as $time => $sensor)
{                 
   echo $time, " max ", $sensor, "<br>\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It does exactly what i want. Now i have to study it and see if i can learn something. :)